# Can we find a subset of $Spec(R)$ not quasi-compact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

If $R$ is a commutative ring with unit, we can easy prove that $Spec(R)$ is quasi-compact. However can you give me an example of $R$ such that a subset $A \subset Spec(R)$ isn't quasi-compact?

Answer (score 5):

$\bigcup_n D(x_n) \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(k[x_1,x_2,\dotsc])$ is not quasi-compact.

More generally, let $R$ be a commutative ring which has an strictly increasing chain of radical ideals $I_1 \subset I_2  \subset \dotsc$ (in particular $R$ is not noetherian). Then the complement of $\bigcap_i V(I_i)$ is open and not quasi-compact.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Take $R$ to be the free Boolean ring on countably many generators. The topological spectrum in this case is homeomorphic to the Stone space consisting of Boolean algebra maps $R \to \mathbf{2}$ with the appropriate Stone topology. By the freeness, this is the space of maps $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbf{2}$, i.e., the space $\mathbf{2}^\mathbb{N}$ with the product topology, i.e., Cantor space. You probably realize that any subspace of this is Hausdorff, and any compact Hausdorff subspace will have to be closed. So then just take $A$ to be any non-closed subset (e.g., an increasing sequence in the middle-thirds model of Cantor space which does not contain its accumulation point).

Comment: So I need a ring that is not noetherian?

Comment: But I have zariski topology on $R$

Comment: (1) For Boolean rings, the Zariski topology coincides with the Stone space topology. (2) The question said nothing about a Noetherian hypothesis. Don't change conditions on me midstream! :-)

Comment: You need a non-Noetherian ring. What makes Noetherian topological spaces so nice is that every open subset is quasicompact.

Comment: _Every_ subset of a noetherian topological space is quasicompact!

Comment: @Zhen Woops, you're right. Not sure why I put that word there.